# Change Jupyterlab startup folder (MacOS: Post Hurricane Catalina)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

After updating (Catalina), and reinstalling anaconda3, my new startup folder is the in my users folder, with no way to navigate outside of the users folder.  I'm just trying to get a cd directory root so I can navigate to my code files.

I've tried navigating via path (file->open from path, adding in Desktop/) won't navigate there.  I've tried navigating directionally out (cd ~/ ) and won't navigate there.  I found a post about this, but it's for Windows.

Please help -- this update is ruining my week.  Half of my paths are ruined, I'm ready to Time Machine or Ebay this garbage.

Comment: Am having the same problem, did you get a fix for this ?

Comment: I created an alias file and navigated through that to desktop, that works as kinda a strange solution -- basically I alias a folder inside startup folder, and place that on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an alias file and navigated through that to desktop, that works as kinda a strange solution -- basically I alias a folder inside startup folder, and place that on desktop.  Only solution I've been able to find, aside from possibly reinstalling from scratch.